# Qual o significado do termo “popular” no contexto de informática/programação?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

Normalmente o termo *popular* significa algo muito conhecido, ou uma pessoa carismática, com muitos amigos e tal...

Mas no contexto de informática (programação), esse termo me parece um tanto genérico.

Uma [simples busca do termo na comunidade SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=popular) retorna resultados como estes:

---

Pergunta: [Popular Spinner](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29463/popular-spinner)

> Em minha aplicação tenho um método retorna uma lista de clientes. Como eu faço para **popular** um Spinner apenas com os nomes dos clientes contidos na Lista?

---

Pergunta: [Popular datagrid com threading](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80724/popular-datagrid-com-threading)

> Estou contraindo uma aplicação Windows Form. Não estou conseguindo **popular** meu datagrid com uma threading [...]

---

[Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354616/jquery-preencher-select/354618#354618) do [@Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam):

> Então basta retirar o async: false, que o select será **populado** normalmente

---

Então, eu poderia, em resumo, dizer que popular é sinônimo de *renderizar dados para o usuário*? Se não, qual o real significado deste termo?

Saliento que o objetivo da pergunta é saber o significado empregando o termo como **verbo**!

Comment: Eu acredito que "preencher" se encaixa melhor, mas não tenho nenhuma referência para dar respaldo e, por isso, não estou respondendo à sua questão.

Comment: Contraiu uma aplicação Windows Form? Coitadinho... tem uma mortalidade alta. :(

Comment: Preencher uma variavel, por exemplo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No contexto de informática, "popular" é um verbo que significa "**preencher com conteúdo**", "**povoar**".

É uma tradução bruta do inglês "populate", que acabou por se implantar no dialeto da informática... é uma coisa que acontece bastante neste meio:

- "Popular" (povoar);
- "Flagar" (sinalizar);
- "Parsar" ou "fazer parse" (processar);
- "Pingar" (... fazer *ping*?)...

Comment: Menção honrosa para «*caracter»: https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/745

Answer (score 3):

Conforme já mencionado pelo @ANeves, o verbo **popular** é um termo criado dentro do ramo de informática e sua origem é oriunda do verbo *populate* em inglês. 
Inclusive, a [Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/popular) já define ***polular*** como verbo, com a devida definição e origem.

> **popular ²**
>   pupuˈlar
>   verbo transitivo
>   INFORMÁTICA importar dados para (uma base de dados); inserir conteúdo em (base de dados) Do inglês (to) populate, «idem»

[Referencia - Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/popular)

Comment: O [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/popular) também tem, com exemplo e tudo.